# What kind of preparation is done on-set when an actor has to play a character in disguise?

Tags: production

This usually happens in fantasy movies where a character drinks a potion or uses magic to disguise himself into another character.

For example, in Harry Potter And The Deathly Hallows, Hermione transforms into Bellatrix when breaking into Gringotts. But Helena Bonham Carter, plays Bellatrix as Hermione is disguise, with mannerism that Emma Watson brings to the character.

In Thor: Ragnarok, Loki disguises himself as Odin & rules Asagard for a while. Here, Sir Anthony Hopkins plays Odin as Loki in disguise, with mannerism like "Oh Shit" that Tom Hiddleston brings to the character.

In Thor: The Dark World, Loki disguises himself as Captain America when Thor breaks him out of prison. Here Chris Evans plays Captain America as Loki in disguise, with mannerisms like mischief that Tom Hiddleston brings to the character.

The question is how do these actors prepare for a situation like this. When they have to play their characters but as a different character in disguise and still keep the characters mannerism intact.

Do the Directors shoot a mock scene with the other actor in order for them to have a reference. ie, did Emma Watson do a mock-scene first for Helena to copy, did Tom do a mock-scene first for Sir Hopkins to copy. How does it work on-set?

Comment: Relevant, but beware it's a big spoiler for a season 3 episode of The Good Place: https://www.vulture.com/2018/12/the-good-place-season-3-janet-episode.html

Answer (score 2):

As with many other scenes, there are rehearsals.

Actors for these kinds of big-budget moves spend a lot of time together and get to study and mime their counterparts when preparing for scenes like this.  It makes sense that they get together and discuss and rehearse mannerisms, speech patterns etc., until they're fairly proficient.

Then they rehearse and shoot scenes in front of the director who refines things until they're happy with the scene.

I don't have any citations here beyond thinking how this could happen.